# Proof that $[x+n] = [x] + n$ for all reals $x$ and all integers $n$

Tags: analysis

Let 
$$[x] := \sup \{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n \leq x \}$$
for all reals $x$.
I want to prove that, if $x$ lies in $\mathbb{R}$ and $n$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$[x+n] = [x] + n.$$
Nevertheless,
by definition I have
$$[x] + n \leq x + n,$$
and 
$$[x+n] \leq x+n.$$
But then? 
What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\;k\le x<k+1\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , then

$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;k+n\le x+n<(k+1)+n\implies$$

$$\lfloor x+n\rfloor=k+n=\lfloor x\rfloor+n$$

Comment: @Kurt My pleasure. Its simplicity adds to its beauty, imo.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}[x+n]&=\sup\{k\in \mathbb Z\mid k\le x+n \}=\sup\{k\in \mathbb Z \mid k-n \le x\}\overset{k-n\to m}=\\&=\sup\{m+n \in \mathbb Z \mid m \le x\}=\\&=n+\sup\{m\in \mathbb Z\mid m \le x\}=\\&=n+[x]\end{align*}$$